# Aligning 3divs horizontally within a container

Tags: html, css, alignment, containers, center

How can I align a div container horizontally and within it 3 divs in css?
See my concept: http://postimg.org/image/9el748gst/

```
   <div id="container">
           <div id="header"> HEADER </div>
           <div id="content"> CONTENT </div>
           <div id="footer"> FOOTER </div> 
   </div>
```

Sorry if I double-post, I just couldn't find the right way to do this.
Thank you!

Comment: If you have fixed width on `#container` then just add `margin:0 auto` to center it horizontally - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/29KL5/)

Comment: Also use `text-align:center` as well to keep the center in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly you can use something like this

**Demo** : http://jsbin.com/zuxunavi/1/

**HTML** :

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"> HEADER </div>
  <div id="content"> CONTENT </div>
  <div id="footer"> FOOTER </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS** :

```
#container{
  min-height:100px;
  height:auto !important;
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#CCC;
  padding:5px;
  overflow:auto
}

#header{
  height:50px;
  background:#FF0000;
  width:95%;
  margin:2.5%;
}
#content{
  height:200px;
  background:#25AAE2;
  width:95%;
  margin:2.5%;
}

#footer{
  height:50px;
  background:#8CC63E;
  width:95%;
  margin:2.5%;
}
```

You can keep this as reference to develop your own html page. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why are you floating those elements?

Comment: @Vucko: Removed the float. I thought it might break the alignment. Tested it now..